# Azure function gets 'Listener unable to start' error on linux

Tags: c#, .net, linux, azure, azure-functions

I am using Ubuntu Linux and I have been having issue when I try to run .Net core 2.2 Azure function app.
A quick googling showed that it could be related to storage somehow but none of them were clear.

Although the runtime seems to start running normally, I get this error after a while:

```
[6/4/2020 8:35:09 am] The listener for function 'FunctionName' was unable to start.
[6/4/2020 8:35:09 am] The listener for function 'FunctionName' was unable to start. Microsoft.Azure.Storage.Common: Connection refused. System.Net.Http: Connection refused. System.Private.CoreLib: Connection refused.
```

Comment: Have you checked your storage account connection string? Storage account required to store function checkpoint data in blob.

Comment: Can you show the local.settings.json?

Comment: Hi, any update?

Comment: @BowmanZhu Yes I did, look at my answer in this post

Answer (score 6, accepted):

So I found the problem. 
I attempted to run my azure function on my windows partition and I was getting a similar error. It turned out the problem was the Azure Storage Emulator in both cases.

To fix it in windows I had to:

- Delete all "AzureEmulatorDb" instances in /%USERPROFILE%
- Then I had to run  "SqlLocalDb i" to find all currently running local Dbs and delete them with "SqlLocalDb delete"
- Lastly, I had to go into the SDK folder and run "./AzureStorageEmulator.exe init -forcecreate" to re-create the azureEmulatorDb and initialise a new configuration for the emulator

The fix in Linux was actually easier:

- I downloaded Azurite, which is an open source Azure Storage emulator (https://github.com/azure/azurite)
- Then I just run it with the "azurite" command before I started my azure function

Comment: I had the exact same issue, when i tried running my Azure Function through Visual Studio, on my M1 Mac. The Linux fix worked like a charm. 
Thank you!