# Azure.Core: Connection refused. System.Net.Http: Connection refused. System.Private.CoreLib: Connection refused

Tags: azure, azure-functions, serverless

I am trying to run an Azure function which is written in Python and running in Linux terminal. When I run the function locally I get the following error.

```
The listener for function 'Functions.endpoint-function' was unable to start.
The listener for function 'Functions.endpoint-function' was unable to start. Azure.Core: Retry failed after 6 tries. Retry settings can be adjusted in ClientOptions.Retry. (Connection refused) (Connection refused) (Connection refused) (Connection refused) (Connection refused) (Connection refused). Azure.Core: Connection refused. System.Net.Http: Connection refused. System.Private.CoreLib: Connection refused.
```

My `local.settings.json` file is:

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "python",
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "UseDevelopmentStorage=true"
  }
}
```

When I deploy and run in the Azure Function app by using `"AzureWebJobsStorage": ""` I get the following error.

```
 [Error]   Executed 'Functions.endpoint-function' (Failed, Id=a60c244c-2125-4c82-902c-48e5f87e2842, Duration=15ms)
```

Any suggestion what is wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried anything to fix it? If so you should list the steps you have taken. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61098214/5209435) might help.